# Rendering HTML from a python String in web2py, generate @usename links python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, web2py

Rendering HTML from a python String in `web2py`

I am trying to render an anchor link in an html file generated server side in web2py

```
<a href="http://app/default/profile/">@username</a>
```

and the link generates correctly; however when I call it in my view `{{=link}}` the page does not render it as HTML.  I have tried using

```
mystring.decode('utf-8')
```

and various other conversions.  Passing it to javascript and back to the page displays the link fine.  Is there something specific about python strings that do not communicate well with html?

In the controller the string is generated by the function call:

```
#code barrowed from luca de alfaro's ucsc cmps183 class examples
def regex_text(s):
    def makelink(match):
        # The title is the matched praase @username
        title = match.group(0).strip()
        # The page is the striped title 'username' lowercase
        page = match.group(1).lower()
        return '%s' % (A(title, _href=URL('default', 'profile', args=[page])))
    return re.sub(REGEX,makelink, s) 

def linkify(s):
    return regex_text(s)

def represent_links(s, v):
    return linkify(s)
```

which replaces @username with a link to their profile and args(0) = username and is sent to the view by a controller call

```
def profile():
    link = linkify(string)
    return dict(link=link)
```

Comment: Can you post your code in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security, web2py templates will automatically escape any text inserted via `{{=...}}`. To disable the escaping, you can wrap the text in the [`XML()` helper](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#XML):

```
{{=XML(link)}}
```

Comment: Thank you, so simple, yet so frustrating.  This worked for me!